# celery slower than multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, celery

I have two computers, c1 and c2. c1 is with two-cores cpu, and c2 is with four-cores cpu. So I connect these two computers with celery using 6 workers to do some tasks. However, when I use multiprocessing in c1 with 6 workers, it seems every worker in celery is slower in multiprocessing? Why is that? So what is the advantage of celery over multiprocessing?

For example:

I have the function:

```
    def readFromHBase(inputData):
        ...
        return data
```

I used celery and multiprocessing to read 1000 files from 100000 samples.

In celery I set up 6 workers crossing two computers c1 and c2, as above. every worker will read 10 files until 1000 files are all obtained.

In multiprocessing, I did the same but set up just in c1 and with a 6 workers pool. Every worker will read 10 files until 1000 files are all obtained.

The results show that every worker in multiprocessing will cost less time than in celery. How does this happen?

Comment: Could you post some code to give us an idea of what you are doing?

Comment: On a single host/server, multiprocessing will outperform celery. Celery shines, though, in a multi-host / multi-server situation, where many nodes are executing tasks stored in the celery queue.

Answer (score 2):

Celery has a queue broker. Multiprocessing does not.
Celery workers pull tasks from the central queue, network one (even on localhost). Multiprocessing use IPC.

Of course, IPC has less overhead than socket layer.

You pay with your performance for your ability to scale.